# What is the difference between "guiar" and "dirigir"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

What is the difference between "guiar" and "dirigir"?  The translation from the English that I want is "guide us in our studies."  Should I use guiar or dirigir?

Comment: Welcome! could you tell us which sources you consulted? I think you should provide a translation attempt.

Comment: I think it's better for you look into the dicciononary [guiar](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=guiar) and [dirigir](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=dirigir)

Answer (score 1):

I would translate

> Please, guide us in our studies.

as

> Por favor, guíenos en nuestros estudios.

"Guide" is translated into Spanish as "guiar". ["Dirigir"](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=dirigir), however, has multiple meanings that translate into different words in English. Here's a few examples from [wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/):

---

> **Es muy independiente; no le gusta que nadie dirija su vida.**
>
> S/he's very independent; s/he wants nobody to run her/his life

---

> **Juan dirige una empresa de publicidad.**
>
> John runs/manages an advertising company.

---

> **Un policía dirigía el tráfico en el cruce.**
>
> A policeman directed the traffic at the junction.

---

Answer (score 1):

I think "dirigir" refers to someone who give you specific directions. As an example, if I say "El trabajo será dirigido por el señor Perez", it means that Mr. Perez will give specific instructions on how to do the work for the enterprise: first workers will clean their hands, then everyone have to check in at entrance, etc. "Guiar" is more like suggesting to someone. Example: "el tutor los guiará durante el proceso". Refers to an advisor who will tell you wich books you "would" read, what exercise you would do to improve your performance. Take a look at the example that guys have written; every example of "dirigir" means someone give specific instructions (policeman is strict on gie instructions like: turn left, stop, etc), Juan manages an advertising company giving instructions to workes who have to do specific task, also who is very independent doesn´t want someone give her/him instructions on how to manage his life, but would accept some suggestions about it, because he/she could or couldn't accept it.

Comment: +1 for explaining the difference between dirigir and guiar

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you "**dirigir**". The spanish dictionary says (http://recursosdidacticos.es/goodrae/definicion.php?palabra=Dirigir):

> 7 tr. Orientar, guiar, aconsejar a quien realiza un trabajo.

Comment: You could say "dirigir una tesis doctoral o un trabajo de investigación" for instance, but that translates into English as "supervise a PhD thesis or a research project". You could say "dirigir un estudio", but again this would translate into English as "conduct a study".

Comment: "Conduct a study" is not the same than "Guide a study". "Conduct" means "encaminar" like "my recommendation is to direct to ..."

Comment: I'm more familiar with the meaning listed in [wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=conduct): conduct a study (perform an investigation) = conducir un estudio. For example: La Universidad de Michigan condujo un estudio sobre psicología.

Comment: In Spanish "to conduct" is not used as you proposed. Take a look at http://recursosdidacticos.es/goodrae/definicion.php?palabra=conducir&lema=no

Comment: I don't want to drag the point any further, but at least I want to show that "conducir un estudio" is in use in Spanish: [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=conducir+*+estudio&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cconducir%20%2A%20estudio%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bconducir%20el%20estudio%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bconducir%20al%20estudio%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bconducir%20un%20estudio%3B%2Cc0) & [books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22conducir%20un%20estudio%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_es). "Conducir un estudio" is a very formal expression that may explain its rare use.

Comment: The competent authority for Spanish language is DRAE (http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/drae), not Google.
Check what DRAE says about "conducir" : http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=conducir